# Using webpack with 'react-hot', 'babel-loader'

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a webpack.config with loaders like this:

```
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel-loader' ]
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        test: /\.js$/
      }
    ],
```

I exclude node_modules because other ways react-hot would get in trouble saying things like [this](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/133)

My problem is that: by excluding node_module, a private `npm` package that needs babel-loader, would not be loaded into the bundle.

How can I manage excluding for each loader?

Comment: Keeping your private packages in a different place (e.g. lib under project folder) would solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `include` property for the loader instead of `exclude`. For example:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app/src"),
      // some module in node_modules folder
    ],
    loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel-loader' ]
  },
  ...
],
```

Note that both [`webpack`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) and [`react-hot-loader`](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/releases/tag/v1.2.4) recommend using `include` over `exclude` whenever possible.